# How to get the row data that include max value in MySQL?

Tags: mariadb-10.4

How to get the total row data that has max(reg_count).
When I try this, it gives me only max reg_count value. I want to get the whole row data that has max reg_count in every albumID.(So like this:  4 Bemisal ha 1 1 8) - total 4 rows

```
SELECT albumID, max(reg_count) as max_count
FROM contentnew 
GROUP BY albumID
```

[image]

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the version of MySQL you are using so I'll assume it's a modern one (8.x). You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify the row you need.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by albumID order by reg_count desc) as rn
  from contentnew
) x
where rn = 1
```

In MySQL 5.x you can use correlated subquery:

```
select *
from contentnew a
where a.reg_count = (
  select max(reg_count) 
  from contentnew b 
  where b.albumID = a.albumID)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your second answer and it worked well. I am a beginner in MySQL. Where can I see the MySQL version? (First answer worked well also, but I am familiar to the second answer, so I used it)

Comment: @Jinyoucheng If the first query worked, then you must be in 8.x. Anyway, you can get the version of MySQL with `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for your help. (Mine was 10.4.11-MariaDB)

Comment: @Jinyoucheng Just a note. For clarity I changed the tag of your question to MariaDB. Even though these two databases were compatible years back, they are now diverging quite a bit. Your solution may work in one and not the other.